# Write custom maven command set using eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-eclipse-plugin

from command line I can write

```
mvn install -Pauto-deploy
```

Is it possible to store this command in my eclipse maven plugin. I want to execute this command by click.

I see only standart things in maven menu:

```
build
clean 
install 
test
```

I want see at this list `my_autodeploy_command`

I am sure it is possible but I don't know how.

Can you show how?

where can I write  `mvn install -Pauto-deploy` ?

Somewhere here?

[image]

**UPDDATE**

for taringamberini

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog is the correct one. Install, the lifecycle phase to run up to, is put into the goals field, your profile (auto-deploy) is put into the Profiles field (without -P):

[image: Run As Dialog]

You could also copy the full line (without leading "mvn") into the Goals field

Comment: What I need type in 'Base directory' ?

Comment: if you open the dialog by right-clicking on your project and selecting "run as -> maven build...", it will be pre-filled. Else either the full path to your project (the directory containing the pom), or `${workspace_loc:/<name of your project>}`

Comment: Yes. and 1 more point.I don't see my new configuration when I click run as ->

Comment: Is it really to make so?

Comment: It won't show in the run as menu. But if you select run as -> Maven build (without ...), it will run your custom configuration if there is exactly one or show you a menu, if you have created multiple configs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to store this command in my eclipse maven plugin.

Yes, it is:

1. In the `Package Explorer` view right click your Maven project
2. choose `Run as` and `Run configurations...`
3. right click on `Maven Build` (node added by your eclipse maven plugin) and choose `New`
4. Compile the filed `Name` for example with `clean_test_install`
5. Compile the field `Base directory`  browsing your maven project directory
6. Compile the field `Goals`  for example with `clean build test install`
7. click `Apply` and close the `Run Configuration`  window

Now, in the tool bar, if you click on the drop down menu at the right of the `Run As ...` button you can see the `clean_test_install` entry.

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Red: I had referred to the ```Run as...``` 's drop down menu in the toolbar while in your update the drop down menu seems the one that apears right clicking on the project in the ```Package Explorer``` view and following ```Run as...```. Too many drop down menu ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in maven plugin in eclipse as below.
Go to debug configuration eclipse --> New configuration in Maven Build
Specify Goals as clean -install and select base directory as project which you want to build. You can also skip test if we want in configuration

Comment: go to debug configuration, and select maven build (double click) it should create new configuration. Now select your base directory i.e project which you want to build by clicking on browse workspace. Enter goals as : clean install deploy (U may need to change as per your requiremnet).

Answer (score 0):

I had an ugly/complicated maven command which launched my project. And On Windows, I wanted to launch it in eclipse - to see the console, and not under a command prompt - where you can't see the console clear. The Maven command was something like:

```
mvn -am -pl web package -DskipTests -P link-repo,tomcat-run,local-jive -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

So blackbuild answer:
"You could also copy the full line (without leading "mvn") into the Goals field"
saved my life!

I just copied the maven command in Goals field and it worked!