# How to change default location(root dir) of pom.xml in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I just want to change the default location of pom.xml file of my maven project in eclipse

```
Current location: MY-Project/pom.xml
Need to change with: My-Project/some_dir/pom.xml
```

**Note**: eclipse should look for the newly located pom.xml and resolve all are the dependencies

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using maven? From cmd or from eclpise's gui?

Comment: Actually both and my build is getting success also

Comment: Ok, for cmd you can override pom's location like this `mvn -f <other pom file>`. For eclipse gui you need to define a custom maven goal which will execute the above command. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399145/write-custom-maven-command-set-using-eclipse-plugin) for details.

Comment: I don't recommend moving the location of pom.xml - it's standard practice to have it in the project's folder.  If you share your code with others, they will expect to see it there.